# Dial VPN connection from a Windows C# service

Tags: c#, vpn

I am trying to develop a Windows service using C# and Visual Studio 2017. I would like to dial up a pre configured VPN connection from within the service.

If I were to place the following line of code in a C# Windows Desktop app it will quickly flash a CMD prompt and dial the VPN:
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "ConnectionName user password");

But it does not work in the service.  I have brought it to this point.  It does not throw an error, it does not dial a connection. It just seems to do nothing as i step through it.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("rasdial.exe", "ConnectionName user password");
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start()
```

Not sure how to fix this or what the next steps would be.  An API would be nice if there was one.

I have done some Googling about this but cannot discover anything so i thought i would take it to the experts.

Thanks.

Stephen Simpson

Comment: What if you run that exe directly from command prompt with the same arguments? Does it work fine?

Comment: Service accounts don't have the same privileges as normal user accounts.

Comment: If I run the command line from the prompt it works find and I can get it to call up the VPN from within a C# windows forms app.  That works too.  But it seems to do nothing from the Windows C# service I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Ken White pointed out that service accounts don't have the same privileges as normal user accounts.  I solved the problem by running the service under a specific user.